# df.mean() / jupyter / pandas alternating axis for output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, mean

I haven't posted many questions, but, I have found a very strange behavior causing alternating output. I'm hoping someone can help shed some light on this.

I am using jupyter and I am creating some data like this:

```
# Use the following data for this assignment:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])
df
```

Now in the next cell I have a couple lines to get the transpose of the DF and then get the mean and standard deviations. However, when I run this cell multiple times it seems that I am getting different output from .mean()

```
df = df.T
values = df.mean(axis=0)
std = df.std(axis=0)
values
```

I am using shift enter to run this second cell and this is what I will get:

> ```
> 1992    33312.107476
> 1993    41861.859541
> 1994    39493.304941
> 1995    47743.550969
> dtype: float64
> ```

And when I run the cell again using shift + enter (Output truncated but you should get the idea)

> ```
> 0         5447.716574
> 1       126449.084350
> 2        41091.469083
> 3       -61754.197831
> 4       223744.364842
> 5        94746.779056
> 6        57607.078825
> 7       109812.089923
> 8        28283.060354
> 9        69768.157194
> 10       32952.030326
> 11       40222.026635
> 12       64786.632304
> 13       17025.266684
> 14      111334.168830
> 15       96067.788206
> 16      -68157.985363
> ```

I have tried changing the axis parameter and removing the axis parameter but the output remains the same

Here is a screen shot incase anyone is interested in duplicating what I have done:

[Jupyter window on my end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EuQI.png)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that in your second cell, you are re-assigning your `df` to be `df.T`, so every time, it is transposing your dataframe again. So what you can do is: **Don't use `df = df.T`**, just say this instead:

```
values = df.T.mean(axis=0)
std = df.T.std(axis=0)
```

Or even better, use `axis=1` (apply it to columns instead of rows) without transposing:

```
values = df.mean(axis=1)
std = df.std(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This definitely helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `describe`

```
df.T.describe()
Out[267]: 
                1992           1993           1994           1995
count    3650.000000    3650.000000    3650.000000    3650.000000
mean    34922.760627   41574.363827   43186.197526   49355.777683
std    200618.445749   98495.601455  140639.407130   70408.448642
min   -632057.636640 -292484.131067 -435217.159232 -181304.694667
25%    -98715.272565  -24771.835741  -49460.639563    -973.422386
50%     34446.219184   41474.621854   43323.557410   49281.270881
75%    170722.706967  107502.446843  136286.933017   97422.070284
max    714855.084396  453834.306915  516751.566696  295427.273677
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me describe. I will definitely remember this.